# What is the TypeScript code to add two different inputs to list in Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have created a form to add 2 different inputs (name and age) to a list.
But I am facing problem to code in typescript file. What is the way to add items to list?

I have written code of my *html* and *typescript* file. I have created function *(onClick)* in my Button, so what code should I write inside this function to add items in list?

I have also written *ngRepeat* directive in *html* code but I don't know how to use it in *typescipt* file.

Html code:

```
<div class="shadow-lg p-5 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
    <ul class = "list-group">
        <li *ngFor="let person of people" class = "list-group-item list-group-item-success">
            {{ person.name }} - {{ person.age }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <ul class = "list-group">
        <li class = "list-group-item list-group-item-warning">

            <input type="name" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Enter Name" [(ngModel)]="name" ngRepeat="detail in people">   <hr/>

            <input type="number" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Enter Age" [(ngModel)]="age" ngRepeat="detail in people">  <hr/>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" (click)="onClick()"> Add </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})

export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string;
  age: number;

  people: any[] = [{
    "name" : "abdul",
    "age" : 20
  }, {
    "name" : "david",
    "age" : 30
  }, {
    "name" : "ben",
    "age" : 40
  }]

  onClick() {
    this.people.push();
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: please add the code or the screenshot of what you are trying to do

Comment: `this.people.push({name: this.name, age: this.age});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your push :

```
onClick() {
  this.people.push({ name: this.name, age: this.age });
}
```

Demo :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3hkex